# Object attribute will not be added to object

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to parse a JSONarray into a C# object.

I can deserialize the object, but the values will not be added to the object.

My object look like this:

```
public class Number
{
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"number":"795272334"}]
```

Can anybody help me?

```
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte);
List<Number> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Number>>(result);
```

Comment: @Liam I edited the post

Comment: That's better but what does *the values will not be added to the object* mean?

Comment: Using serialize in javascript client code, then the controller method take an array or a list of string, that you cast in list number. Someting like this.

Comment: Why is your string a byte array originally? Does `result` contain that json exactly? No encoding or slashes, etc?

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger From experience I have had issues deserializing as a list. Try using `Number[]` instead. If you really need a list then you can take the result and pass it to `new List<Number>(result)`

Comment: after some testing this is working, https://tio.run/##TY/BSgMxEIbPzVMMOW0PBmmVolt7WUGQWgUPHro97MaxRNJEMtOKLvvsa9K0YA6Bmfm/yRdNF9oHHIY9GbeF1x9i3JUiVyv8Zu/If7B6JO/O7RxSlbcWNZuYUA/oMBhdCvG1b63RoG1DBKv9rsUgOgHxnCbEIS1xxxF0sEUugdLVi15k7uWEEDcckYM37/DUGFeMj@1OjJaGeJ7XL8DGAu4gOVbeHTCwukeKQo01v/jcfkbN@X9iUch1V8vsUMvbWs5uriezyXR6Vct@I8elGFXp5xbVWzCMS@OwSM@sLzcqYzGTXJL0MPwB

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple example for serialize and deserialize object based on your class

```
private String _json { get; set; }

public class Number
{
    public string number { get; set; }
}

private void Serialize()
{
    //Initialize  list object
    List<Number> list = new List<Number>();
    //add one item
    list.Add(new Number()
    {
        number = "795272334"
    });
    //Serialize list object into json string
    _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
}

private void Deserialize()
{
    //initialize list object
    List<Number> list = new List<Number>();
    //deserealize json string into list object
    list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Number>>(_json);
}
```